# Integral related to harmonic functios

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

It suppose to be a easy task. But I couldn't solve it (I guess I can't learn much analysis).
If $ u $ is harmonic, in the middle of my problem, I need to prove that the integral
$ \int _ {\partial \Omega } \displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial v} d s_x =0 $
THis $ v $ denotes the unit exterior normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Green's first identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities),

$$
\int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\,ds =
\int_{\Omega} (\Delta u + \nabla 1 \cdot \nabla u)\,dV = 0,
$$
since $\Delta u = 0$ by assumption and $\nabla 1 = \mathbf{0}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a consequence of Divergence theorem, isn't it? You have that u is harmonic, so 
$$
\Delta u =\nabla\cdot \nabla u=0.
$$
Now integrate over $\Omega$ and apply the divergence theorem.